# Create regex patterns using iterator

Tags: python, regex, pandas, python-re

I have a DataFrame with a lot of columns. Every column has a csv file catalogue named after the column but not exactly. The name of the column is included in the name of its file plus some letters and words.  What i'm trying to do is to create a regex patter for each column in order for me to get the file name, import it to pandas and merge both Dataframes, but i can not manage to get the "r" in front of the pattern.

This is what i'm trying to do:

```
import re
import pandas as pd

data={"one":[1,2,3,4,5],"two":[6,7,8,9,10]}
left_df=pd.DataFrame(data)
routes={"wordsone.csv":"c:\route\route\one.csv",
       "wordstwo.csv":"c:\route\route\two.csv"}
column_names=list(left_df.columns)

for i in column_names:
    pattern="\w*"+i+"\w*\.csv"
    # This pattern will be used to get the file name associated to the column name
    
    filename=re.findall(pattern,list(routes.keys()))
    #here i'm expecting to get the name of the file
    
    filepath=routes[filename]
    #here im expecting to get the file rout
    
    right_df=pd.read_csv(filepath)
    #Create a Dataframe to merge with left_dataframe
    
    left_df=pd.merge(left_df,right_df,how="left",on=i)
    #Add right_DF to left_df
    
return left_df
```

but i get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-257-0d70c9171983> in <module>
      9 for i in column_names:
     10     pattern="\w*"+i+"\w*\.csv"
---> 11     filename=re.findall(pattern,list(routes.keys()))
     12     filepath=routes[filename]
     13     right_df=pd.read_csv(filepath)

~\Anaconda3\lib\re.py in findall(pattern, string, flags)
    239 
    240     Empty matches are included in the result."""
--> 241     return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
    242 
    243 def finditer(pattern, string, flags=0):

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

How can i get this to work or am I approaching this problem on an incorrect way?

I've tried a lot of ways to get something like r"pattern" but python each and every time changes or erases the "" or the "".

Comment: if you have " in your pattern you must escape them

Comment: do you mean like this? pattern="\\w*"+i+"\\w*\\.csv"  ?   i still get the same error

Comment: it's not necessary, I just say if you have " in your pattern, you must escape them, anyway if you provide sample text and expected result maybe I can help you

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. _i can not manage to get the "r" in front of the pattern_ What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

re.findall requires a string of variables rather than the list of variables you are passing. Make string from your keys list and pass that to findall.
Also, note the backslashes create an issue so to print those without escaping each one use repr()

```
keys_list = list(routes.keys())
print(keys_list)
keys_string = ','.join(keys_list)
print(keys_string)

for i in column_names:
    pattern="\w*"+i+"\w*\.csv"
    filename = re.findall(pattern,keys_string)
    print(filename)

    filepath = routes[filename[0]]
    print(repr(filepath))

    Output from print statements:
    ['wordsone.csv', 'wordstwo.csv']
    wordsone.csv,wordstwo.csv
    ['wordsone.csv']
    'c:\route\route\\one.csv'
    ['wordstwo.csv']
    'c:\route\route\two.csv'
```